# "Implied" is to "explicit" as "implication" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, analogy

I am looking for an antonym of implication that is related in the same way that *implied* and *explicit* are related, where *explicit* means "expressed". This antonym should also fit the following analogy:

*Imply* is to *state* as *implication* is to ***_*__*_*_**.

---

*Example:*

> Alice: "Your argument/statement implies X."
>
> Bob: "But what I explicitly stated contradicts your perceived
>   implication!"

I think it would be very nice to use a word that would mean the exact opposite of *implication* to emphasize how incorrect a perceived implication is when it contradicts what someone had plainly said or written.

Bob could say, "But my statement/explanation/argument contradicts your perceived implication," which gets the point across, but IMO doesn't convey the full gravity of Alice's blunder that an antonym of *implication* would. Bob wants to succinctly emphasize that what was plainly stated, when taken at face value, contradicts what Alice thought was implied.

M-W defines [*explicate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explication) as "to give a detailed explanation of." Does that mean that *explication* is a "detailed explanation"? If so, *explication* would function well if Bob had indeed provided a detailed explanation or argument. However, if Bob had simply offered a statement or two, I don't think *explication* would work well.

In short, Bob should say: "My ***_*_** contradicts your perceived implication."

Comment: If there was a need for such a word, there would be one, 'but as it isn't, it ain't. That's logic', as Tweedldee said.

Comment: 'explication' is just a fancy version  of 'explanation'.

Comment: @&: I'm having trouble understanding your "need" - could you perhaps explain how Bob would use this word in a sentence, if it existed?  Feel free to use a ________ (blank).

Comment: thanks for the edit, J.R. I've complied with your request.

Comment: Bob could quite happily respond with "But my [explication](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+explication&oq=define+explication&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&q=explication&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=yVWIUKDSOKvM0AXp7oHABQ&ved=0CB8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9cc6ce1e3edfb4fe&bpcl=35466521&biw=1084&bih=866) contradicts your perceived implication!" *(the act of making clear or removing obscurity from the meaning of a word or symbol or expression etc.)*. I think this is a Not Constructive peeve.

Comment: ...... exegesis?

Comment: The reason why explication doesn't work in the Alice/Bob context is because explication means to make clear. If Alice is saying something contradictory to what Bob has tried to articulate, then Bob has not explicated anything at all. Really, he should say, "My **percieved** explication contradicts your perceived implication". Or even "My **percieved** explication contradicts your perceived **explication**" (since Alice's claim is that a **logical** implication is **explicit** in Bob's argument).

Comment: An explicit implication. That's a new one, @Lucas

Comment: @ampersand been around for ~2300yrs: it's an old new one ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Declaration](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/declaration): *a formal or explicit statement or announcement*

> In short, Bob should say: "My ***declaration*** contradicts your perceived implication."

Comment: Thanks, Fuhrmanator. I think this most captures the concept I am trying to convey, which is the "expressed" nature of a statement.  http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/declaration demonstrates this in its definition of *declaration.*

Comment: Edited accordingly, @ampersand

Answer (score 7):

I think your expression *"explicitly stated"* is a bit redundant, and I'd use **statement** as the word you want.

I don't think one can state something implicitly...

Comment: I agree - *statement, declaration, exposition, pronouncement, attestation, assertion* are words that fit OP's context.

Comment: @SF, it is redundant to make a point. See the definition of declaration here: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/declaration.  I think 'statement' is close, but see my question for my issues with it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not so sure about assertion. While act of assertion itself is explicit, the fact being asserted may be implicit. (I assert my dominant position by punching your face. The punch is explicit, the domination is implicit.)

Comment: @SF.: Obviously all words have a spread of meaning - *assertion* is quite capable of having the relevant meaning(s) required here.

Comment: [A few hundred examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22implicit%20statement%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) of *implicit statement*

Comment: @Henry, in the IT sense, like the FORTRAN books, it's usually "the `IMPLICIT` statement", not *an implicit statement*. I also noticed it appearing in sense that existence of the statement is implicit - "text makes an implicit statement" is used as an expression for "I conclude this text implies". But I concede, yes, the expression is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Although I agree with the notion that were there a need for such a word, one would exist, I couldn't resist the attempt. So if an implication is something which has been implied, and therefore not stated, we're looking for a word that means "that which has been explicitly said". The closest I can get is `assertion`.

Comment: +1 I like assertion, Dominic. I'd give the answer to you, but 'declaration' works equally well, and I've voted. Thank you!

Comment: @Dominic, see my question to JustinC below: Does an implication always have to be implied, as you state here?

Comment: "Were there a need for such a word, one would exist" -- citation needed.

Comment: @LarsH No citation needed. I as paraphrasing BarrieEngland in this thread

Comment: That's a sufficient citation for your usage: knowing that you are echoing @BarrieEngland. I would like to trace the authority or reasoning behind this statement back further though. I'm curious why we should think it to be true and whether there are studies confirming or disconfirming the thesis.

Comment: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Xghrs_N4Vuo#t=320s) at 05:20, Christopher Hitchens corrects his use of "imply" to "assert." Just found it interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Some potential choices:

- Exposition/Expound
- Elucidation/Elucidate
- Spelling out/Spell out

There's no one definitive antonym that I can think of, but those are close.

Answer (score 3):

The analogy is not so straightforward.

> implicit->implication

is not a direct addition of suffixes semantically.

Conceptually, an implication is the consequences of some premises; something implicit is an unstated assumption or a set of rules.

'Explicit' is something that is stated out loud or given by instance. So the corresponding concept to an implication, would be one of those instances or an

> **example**

This doesn't fit the same register. In another direction, one might what the thing that is stated out loud and that might be an

> **explanation**

Comment: I see your point. Perhaps the question should be "Implied is to explicit as implication is to _____"

Comment: well, there you go, there's no real verb that fits the analogy for 'imply'. 'Exply'? No, that's not a thing. 'Explain'? That doesn't really correspond.

Comment: You are correct. When I posted, I was hoping someone would offer a noun I had not thought of. I think 'state' functions well as an antonym for 'imply' in the sense that I am looking for, but 'statement' doesn't fit the analogy *to the degree that I want it to.*

Answer (score 1):

[**Explication**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explication)

It means to say in a clear, direct way. Rather than implication, to say in an unclear indirect way.

> "to give a detailed explanation of." Does that mean that explication is a "detailed explanation" ?

No, not always. It just means to make something obvious, usually. Often it requires details to make something clear, but doesn't always.

Answer (score 0):

How about [dissociation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dissociate?q=dissociate) from dissociate?

> dissociate - to consider as separate and not related

If you provide context, it may help, I imagine that a phrase is more likely to be useful to you than a single word (e.g. 'distances x from...', 'makes x seem less likely').

Answer (score 0):

To imply is to act or communicate from a point of consequence, not from the cause.  If you imply something, you have already fast forwarded past the details that led to a conclusion and work from that point onward with little regard for preceeding activity.  To infer is to work backwords from the point of consequence and further postulate the activities and cause that led to the current consequence.

I am tempted to suggest exonerate, or exoneration; but that is not quite right either.

```
(transitive) To free from an obligation, responsibility or task.
(transitive) To free from accusation or blame.
```

However, rebut or refute seem closer to the desired counter activity of imply or implication; as it distinctly puts the party in opposition at a similar point of time with regard to the cause that led to the current consequence.

```
refute vb
1. (tr) to prove (a statement, theory, charge, etc.) of (a person) to be false or incorrect; disprove
2. to deny (a claim, charge, allegation, etc.)
```

Comment: Does an implication always have to be implied? It seems that both an inference and an implication can be arrived at by an audience without the speaker implying anything. In that sense, *inference* and *implication* are interchangeable. I think these considerations can give clarity to what it is that I am trying to ask here! What do you think?

Comment: If something can be correctly inferred, then it is at least implicit in what was said. You might indeed argue that `implied` implies some amount of intent on the part of the speaker. However, to answer the question here, this distinction is surely moot.

Comment: @ampersand inference and implication are not interchangeable.  The term *inference* makes it *explicit* that the unstated meaning is applied by the reader.  It could be argued that (at least in common usage) *implication* leaves open the question of who provided the extra meaning, but that is not equivalent.